# Apply Chart formatting only on the specific range of slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

[image]

How can I apply the chart formatting only on specific range of slides. Please assist.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code - copy the *text* and use the `{}` button to format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simpler way:

```
Private Sub Okay_Click()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    
    For x = 1 To 3
        For Each shp In ActivePresentation.Slides(x).Shapes
            'Do stuff to shapes
        Next shp
    Next x
End Sub
```